# javascript delete item during async.map

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, node-async

I'm using async.map to iterate over an array and executing some async functions on each item. In some cases I need to delete the item from the original array, I was wondering if this is possible, I tried calling the callback with two null params,

```
cb(null,null)
```

but this doesn't work. I tried looking around a bit, but couldn't find anything on this specific case. Is there a way to achieve this or not? Thanks.

EDIT:short code snippet

```
async.map(page['canvasData']['objects'], function (elem, cb) {
    if (elem['type'] == "picturebox") {
        //async opeartions
        cb(null, elem);
    } else cb(null, null);
}
```

Comment: can you add a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 1):

If determining whether or not to remove an element can be done synchronously (like in your example), you can just use a regular `Array#filter` before calling `async.map`:

```
var filteredObjects = page.canvasData.objects.filter(function () {
    return elem.type === "picturebox";
});
// filteredObjects is a copy of page.canvasData.objects, with
// non-picturebox elements removed
async.map(filteredObjects, function (elem, cb) {
    // async operations...
        // more async operations...
            // more async operations...
                cb(null, elem);

}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) { ... }
    else {
        console.log("Result: " + result);
    }
});
```

Comment: this would actually be a good solution, and probabily I will go with this one, but I would like not to iterate 2 times over the same array... so doing it into async.map would probablybe a better solution. hoewer this is good to. thank's